# DataWeave increment variable in json

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have this json

```
{
    "key1": "value1" ,
    "key2": "value2" ,
    ......
    "key20": "value20" ,
    "retryCount": 1
}
```

how do I increment the retry count without creating a transformation that mentions all the other keys and values. So I don't want to do this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    key1: vars.originalPayload.key1 ,
    key2: vars.originalPayload.key2 ,
    ......
    key20: vars.originalPayload.key20 ,
    retryCount: (vars.originalPayload.retryCount default 0) + 1
}
```

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by incrementing the retry count? What is a retry count in the context of this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to update the value of key retryCount without modifying the rest of the input payload. You can use the [update operator](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/news/anypoint-platform/update-fields-with-dataweave/) for that.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
        case count at .retryCount ->  count + 1
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::util::Values
---
payload update "retryCount" with payload.retryCount + 1
```

Comment: If you only need to update a single value this answer is more compact. If you need multiple updates see my answer. Both use the same operator.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the two approaches based on your requirement:

1. Using the "update" operator:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
        case counter at .retryCount ->  counter + 1
}
```

2. Using the "update" function:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::util::Values
---
payload update "retryCount" with payload.retryCount + 1
```

Approach 1 is more optimized:

1. importing a library is always a costlier process
2. use of "update" operator can be used as a switch case that is more efficient in case of multiple updates operations